# TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str // working with dict

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to define a procedure, `involved(courses, person)`, that takes as input a courses structure and a person and returns a Dictionary that describes all the courses the person is involved in.

Here is my `involved(courses, person)` function:

```
def involved(courses, person):
    for time1 in courses:
        for course in courses[time1]:
            for info in time1[course]:
                print info
```

Here is my dictionary:

```
courses = {
    'feb2012': { 'cs101': {'name': 'Building a Search Engine',
                           'teacher': 'Dave',
                           'assistant': 'Peter C.'},
                 'cs373': {'name': 'Programming a Robotic Car',
                           'teacher': 'Sebastian',
                           'assistant': 'Andy'}},
    'apr2012': { 'cs101': {'name': 'Building a Search Engine',
                           'teacher': 'Dave',
                           'assistant': 'Sarah'},
                 'cs212': {'name': 'The Design of Computer Programs',
                           'teacher': 'Peter N.',
                           'assistant': 'Andy',
                           'prereq': 'cs101'},
                 'cs253': 
                {'name': 'Web Application Engineering - Building a Blog',
                           'teacher': 'Steve',
                           'prereq': 'cs101'},
                 'cs262': 
                {'name': 'Programming Languages - Building a Web Browser',
                           'teacher': 'Wes',
                           'assistant': 'Peter C.',
                           'prereq': 'cs101'},
                 'cs373': {'name': 'Programming a Robotic Car',
                           'teacher': 'Sebastian'},
                 'cs387': {'name': 'Applied Cryptography',
                           'teacher': 'Dave'}},
    'jan2044': { 'cs001': {'name': 'Building a Quantum Holodeck',
                           'teacher': 'Dorina'},
               'cs003': {'name': 'Programming a Robotic Robotics Teacher',
                           'teacher': 'Jasper'},
                     }
    }
```

When I'm trying to test my code:

```
>>>print involved(courses, 'Dave')
```

Python give me an error:

```
for info in time1[course]:
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
```

How can I fix that?

Thanks.

Comment: please help
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72428094/extracting-values-from-numpy-array

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`time1` is the key of the most outer dictionary, eg, `feb2012`. So then you're trying to index the string, but you can only do this with integers. I think what you wanted was:

```
for info in courses[time1][course]:
```

As you're going through each dictionary, you must add another nest.

Answer (score 8):

Actually I think that more general approach to loop through dictionary is to use [iteritems()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.iteritems):

```
# get tuples of term, courses
for term, term_courses in courses.iteritems():
    # get tuples of course number, info
    for course, info in term_courses.iteritems():
        # loop through info
        for k, v in info.iteritems():
            print k, v
```

output:

```
assistant Peter C.
prereq cs101
...
name Programming a Robotic Car
teacher Sebastian
```

Or, as Matthias mentioned in comments, if you don't need keys, you can just use [itervalues()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.itervalues):

```
for term_courses in courses.itervalues():
    for info in term_courses.itervalues():
        for k, v in info.iteritems():
            print k, v
```

Comment: When you don't need the key you could use [itervalues](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.itervalues) instead.

Comment: Yep, thanks for addition, I don't know if OP wants to use keys, but I should notice that

Answer (score -1):

I see that you are looking for an implementation of the problem more than solving that error. Here you have a possible solution:

```
from itertools import chain

def involved(courses, person):
    courses_info = chain.from_iterable(x.values() for x in courses.values())
    return filter(lambda x: x['teacher'] == person, courses_info)

print involved(courses, 'Dave')
```

The first thing I do is getting the list of the courses and then filter by teacher's name.

Comment: actually it's possible to do without chain - `[i for x in courses.values() for i in x.values() if i["teacher"] == person]`